# Swift and XCode 7 beta 2 are not displaying the metadata of the songs playing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm doing a test program dealing with audio and tableView, right now I have the controller working and playing the chosen song correctly, but I'm trying to display the metadata from the mp3 file and is not doing anything currently I have it like this:

Function to print the data:

```
func testAudioStuff(testURL testURL: NSURL) {

        let audioInfo = AVPlayerItem(URL: testURL)
        let metaDataList = audioInfo.asset.metadata as [AVMetadataItem]

        //here it should print something it does not

        for item in metaDataList {

            if item.commonKey == nil {

                continue
            }

            if let key = item.commonKey, let value = item.value {

                print(key)
                print(value as! String)

                if key == "title" {

                    print(key)
                    print("here is the title" + (value as! String))
                }

                if key == "artist" {

                    print(key)
                    print("here is the artist" + (value as! String))

                }

                if key == "artwork" {

                    print("here is the artwork" + (value as! String))
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Function to play the music:

```
func playSelectedMusic(song: Int, section: Int) {

        if section == 1 {

            //print(NSBundle.mainBundle().description + "\(song)  \(section)")

            if let starMusic = productsAndMusic["Music"] {

                //print("We are looking at \(starMusic[song])")

                let play = starMusic[song].componentsSeparatedByString(".")[0]
                //print(play)

                if let fileToPlay = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(play, ofType: "mp3") {

                    //print(fileToPlay)


                    testAudioStuff(testURL: NSURL(string: fileToPlay)!)

                    do {

                        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: fileToPlay)!)


                    } catch Errors.GeneralError {


                    } catch let error as NSError {

                        print("i dunno this does not comes with instructions \(error)")
                    } catch let something as ErrorType {

                        print("somehting else \(something)")
                    }

                    player.prepareToPlay()
                    player.play()
                }

                //player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(play, ofType: "mp3")!))
                //player.prepareToPlay()


                //print(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(play, ofType: "mp3"))
            }
            //print(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource((productsAndMusic["Music"]![song] as String).componentsSeparatedByString(".")[0], ofType: "mp3")!)
            //print((productsAndMusic["Music"]![song] as String).componentsSeparatedByString(".")[0])

        } else {


        }

    }
```

As I mentioned it plays the selected song in the simulator but it does not print the metadata, why?, any help? Is in Xcode 7 beta 2.

I have tried something, but no dice, this:

```
var secondTestTitle: AVAsset = AVAsset(URL: testURL)
print(secondTestTitle.description)
var metaStuff: [AVMetadataItem] = secondTestTitle.commonMetadata as [AVMetadataItem]
print(metaStuff.count)
```

Result:

```
<AVURLAsset: 0x78ea3930, URL = /Users/pedro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/304FE5A7-9506-4A9B-B685-5CDBE9AFB4C4/data/Containers/Bundle/Applica ... ock1.mp3>
0
```

Comment: Add more logging. You've for a `for..in` loop and lot of `if let` - you need to know what you're actually getting in each of those.

Comment: By the way, this is stupid: `metadata as [AVMetadataItem]`

Comment: Yes I have it now like var metaStuff: [AVMetadataItem] = secondTestTitle.asset.commonMetadata as! [AVMetadataItem], I'm getting empty [] and 0 count

Comment: In the firs few lines returns [] so is not even starting.

Comment: It is "starting". It's empty.

Comment: Ok and how do I make it take the current song metadata and update it?

Comment: I don't know what "make it take the current song metadata and update it" means. Why do you think the file has metadata?

Comment: how do I take the current playing song and get the metadata? I have placed the artist name and the genre and some other things in itunes, so I'm hopping to get them.

Comment: "I have placed the artist name and the genre and some other things in itunes" You have? So how are you accessing this song? Is it in the device's music library?

Comment: No, no I have placed the data in the song via iTunes and then copy the file to XCode and it is in the main bundle

Comment: So you are just saying `URLforResource` to get the file?

Comment: I'm using var secondTestTitle: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: testURL) then var metaStuff: [AVMetadataItem] = secondTestTitle.asset.commonMetadata as! [AVMetadataItem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an MP3 file in your app bundle, then let's suppose it is called *test.mp3*. Then you can say:

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension:"mp3")
let asset = AVAsset(URL: url!)
let meta = asset.metadata
print(meta)
```

If you don't see any metadata in the console when you say that, then this file has no metadata.

However, that's not what I would do, because it's not a very realistic test — and it isn't likely to be very useful, because most information is not written into the file as metadata. More likely, you're going to want to know about a song in the user's Music library. In that case you would use the Media Player framework, as I describe [in my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch29.html#_exploring_the_music_library).

Comment: Yes I see the meta, is working thanks, I was using NSURL(string: fileToPlay)! not urlforresource i dunno what is the difference.